# Plane equation - geometry (algebra).

Tags: linear-algebra

Write an equation of a plane cutting the  coordinate system in $A(0,0,1)$, $B(1,2,3)$, $C(-1,2,0)$.

Should I calculate vectors $AB$ and $AC$ first? Any clues?

Comment: What do you means with ''cutting the coordinate system'' ? The points $B$ and $C$ are not on the coordinate axis.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** A plane is uniquely determined by three non-colinear points. It doesn't matter which order you calculate your vectors.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use vectors.

Let us assume that your plane doesn't pass through the origin, i.e., that its equation has the form

$$ax+by+cz=1$$

It suffices now to express that this equation is verified for $(x,y,z)=(0,0,1),...$ etc, yielding a system of 3 linear equations in the 3 unknown coefficients, and solve it; giving a unique solution c=1, then $b=-\frac14$ and $a=-\frac32$, proving a posteriori that our guess (the plane does not pass through the origin) was right.

Edit 1: It is possible, but less practical, to work with an equation of the form

$$\tag{1}Ax+By+Cz+D=0$$

with 4 unknown coefficients $A,B,C,D$. The resulting system (3 equations with 4 unknowns) hasn't a unique solution, but a one dimensional vector space of solutions. This is because if $(1)$ is a solution, $kAx+kBy+kCz+kD=0$ is also a solution.

Edit 2: (see formula (18) in (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Plane.html)). A compact solution using a $4 \times 4$ determinant equal to zero is as follows. The determinant comes from a matrix constituted in the following way: pile up the row vectors defined by the coordinates of the 3 points and the "generic" point of the plane $(x,y,z)$ and add a fourth column of ones.

$$\begin{vmatrix}0&0&1&1\\1&2&3&1\\-1&2&0&1\\x&y&z&1\end{vmatrix}=0$$

It only remains to expand this determinant.

Comment: And the equation of a plane is -1.5x-0.25y+1-1=0?

Comment: If you take this equation $Ax+By+Cz+D=0$ of a plane with 4 unknowns, you end up with a system of 3 equations with 4 unknowns; this will result in a non unique solution, more exactly a one dimensional vector space of solutions. This is because if $(A,B,C,D)$ is a solution, any multiple is $(kA,kB,kC,kD)$ is also a solution. What I did is to assume $D \neq 0$ and take $k=-\dfrac{1}{D}$.

Comment: That's right: this is the equation.

Comment: Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: I add an edit to my answer.

Comment: This seems like a terribly complicated solution to a very simple problem. Using $(x-p) \cdot (u \times v) = 0$ gives an equation effortlessly, no need to solve three equations in four unknowns.

Comment: My first solution is not at all "terribly complicated". My 2nd solution takes into account the discussion with the OP who is possibly a beginner, more at ease with systems of equations. There is still a 3rd one that I intended to write which is essentialy like yours; but what I fear with very compact solutions like the one you propose is that it is a little above the real level of knowledge of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Given a fixed point $p$ in the plane , and two vectors $u,v$ in the plane, the equation of the plane is $$(x-p)\cdot(u\times v)=0$$

Here $x-p$ is the vector connecting an arbitrary point $x$ to the point $p$. The cross product $u \times v$ is a vector perpendicular to both $u$ and $v$ and so perpendicular to the plane. The dot product $(x-p)\cdot(u\times v)$ being zero means that $x-p$ and $u \times v$ are perpendicular, i.e. $x$ lies in the plane.

We can close $p=\vec{OA}$, $u = \vec{AB}=\vec{OB}-\vec{OA}$ and $v=\vec{AC}=\vec{OC}-\vec{OA}$. Hence:

\begin{eqnarray*}
[(x,y,z)-(0,0,1)] \cdot [(1,2,2) \times (-1,2,-1)] &=& 0 \\ \\
(x,y,z-1) \cdot (-6,-1,4) &=& 0 \\ \\
-6x -y + 4z-4 &=& 0 \\ \\
6x + y -4z &=& -4
\end{eqnarray*}